# Magento 2 - Why do I always have to manually reindex?

Tags: magento2, cron, indexer, magento-cron, cronjobs

I have setup my cronjob and it runs fine. But sometimes we have to manually execute `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` to manually reindex everything, otherwise new customers are not showing in the backend. I think because we are using the extension BSS Commerce Customer Approval, which we need to approve customers manually before accepting them.

This is very annoying and it should be done by the cron job automatically.

Why do we always have to run the cron job manually, is there a bug in that extension or is it normal? Should I create a new custom cron job where I index everything once a day?

Comment: How your reindexes are setup? On Save or On Schedule? If On Save, try to change it to On Schedule. Are You sure that Your crons are correctly setup (on Server and in Admin panel)?

Comment: You have to make sure that your extension invalidate the customer cache /index correctly after any change that could affect customers, otherwise they wont be reindexed